# Globally force SSL on all pages

Tags: htaccess, ssl, https

Right now my domain `www.example.com` is setup to force HTTPS and it works. The site also correctly links everything to HTTPS. (there are no occurences of HTTP in the database anywhere).

But if you are visiting a subpage, you can change the url to HTTP again, for example `http://example.com/subpage/` and it will not enforce HTTPS.

I have this rule in my `.htaccess` in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Any ideas what the cause of this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To globally redirect all your pages to HTTPS add the following lines to your `.htaccess`:

```
# Globally force SSL.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This should be placed directly after `RewriteEngine on` if you have no previous rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `htaccess` rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Don't forget to save permalinks after any rewrite rule change.

Comment: I've tried adding it and also replacing it with the previous code, neither works on subpages but thanks. 
edit: missed the permalinks thing, will try

Comment: Same result after updating permalinks with that code and replacing that code. The mainpage works and links correctly to all https pages, but the subpages can be manually called as http and do not change to their https equivalent.

Comment: Try this plugin, [https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/)