# My site doesn't redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, http

I have SSL certificate activated on my website.
I did change the settings:

```
setting > general
```

and edit `wp-config.php` to force HTTPS:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

The problem is, the redirect doesn't work and both versions of the site, HTTP and HTTPS, are accessible.

I checked my `.htaccess` file.
It seems everything is correct:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_.+|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/(.+/)?feed/?|/(?:.+/)?embed/|/checkout/(.*)|/cart/|/my-account/(.*)|/wc-api/v(.*)|/(index\.php/)?wp\-json(/.*|$))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

I have **WP-ROCKET** plugin and I think this is the main source of the problem
because whenever I clear the cache and refresh the site from HTTP address it redirects correctly
but just one time

Comment: this problem appeared when I changed my server

Comment: would you please explain or write the full answer ? what should be on?

Comment: Issues with the plugin are off topic here, please contact the plugin maintainer directly. And give the [help] a good read to get familiar with site guidelines.

Comment: in a real-world scenario, people are dealing with websites full of plugins

Comment: [wordpress.se] is nomen est omen mainly about development. Third party plugins are off topic as per guidelines.

Comment: This already has an answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334326/30597

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally force SSL on all pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274097/globally-force-ssl-on-all-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with adding this simple rules to your `.htacces`s file
you can override any possible conflict with plugins and redirect issues

don't forget to add these lines to the beginning of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite conditions, line 4 to 6 in your code, apply when https is active, so you are redirecting from https to https. Consquently you should change the conditions to check, if https is not active, ergo `!on` and `!^443$` and `!https`. Additionally I'm not sure about the rule `RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]`, probably something WP Rocket specific and out of scope here, which is why I suggest to possibly replace it with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`.

In conclusion, I'd say, replace line 4 to 7 of your `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: now my site doesnt load at all, even when I put the original .htaccess back

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: Clear your browser cache. The code in my answer generally works, I use it all the time. So my best guess is, it doesn't work nicely with setup related to the plugin you use.

Comment: my website doesnt load anymore!!! what did you do ?
I can only rename .htaccess to .htaccess1 to get it back
but in that case many probelms and errors I see in the admin area

what did you do ?

Comment: I cleared the cache, I replaced everything back
still doesnt load

Comment: I just want my site back

Comment: @CameronA I didn't do anything. The code isn't harmful. Revert the changes and clear caches, browser, caching plugin, etcetera.